# Using class based views in django how would I insert data into a join table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

for example I have 3 classes defined as such

```
class Timecard(models.Model):
    site_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contractor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Job(models.Model):
    job_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    max_hours = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    time_card = models.ManyToManyField(Timecard, through="Timecard_Job")

class Timecard_Job(models.Model):
    time_card = models.ForeignKey(Timecard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hours_worked = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I have the following class governing my view

```
class FillTimecard(CreateView):
    model = Timecard
    form_class = CreateTimeCardForm
    template_name = 'timesheet/timesheetSubmit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("index")
```

finally I have the following form class

```
class CreateTimeCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Timecard
        fields = ['site_code', 'contractor_name', 'date','job']


    job = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Job.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select
    )
```

When I select the job from the drop down I want to also be able to enter the hours worked on that specific job and that be inserted into the join table.

If someone can just provide resources that will help me achieve this it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you have done with the `job` field, a new field can be added to your form as the docs explain [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).

Essentially:

```py
class CreateTimeCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    job = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Job.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.Select
    )
    hours_worked = forms.DecimalField(label="Hours worked", min_value=0, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        model = Timecard
        fields = ['site_code', 'contractor_name', 'date']
```

Then you should implement `clean()` and `save()` methods in `CreateTimeCardForm` to be sure that the data is valid and to create the associations with other models, saving `hours_worked`.